# Cast QVariant to QList<MyClass> from a json string

Tags: c++, arrays, json, qt, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize `MyClass` from JSON.

```
//MyClass.h
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(const MyClass& other);
    ~MyClass();

    int Counter = 0;
    QString Name;
    QVector<QString> NamesList;
    QJsonObject toJson() const;

};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass);
```

The json string is:

```
{
    "ClassList": [
        {
            "Counter": 100,
            "Name": "My Name",
            "NamesList": [
                "Name 1",
                "Name 2",
                "Name 3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Counter": 5555,
            "Name": "2My Name",
            "NamesList": [
                "2Name 1",
                "2Name 2",
                "2Name 3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can get the ClassList in QVariant by:

```
QVariantMap json_map = DeserializeFromJson(text);
QVariant listVariant = json_map["ClassList"];
```

But I cannot cast the `listVariant` to `QList<MyClass>`.
I've tried the following snippets and every time the result is empty.

```
QList<MyClass> myList = listVariant.value<QList<MyClass> >(); // Empty
QList<MyClass> list = qvariant_cast<QList<MyClass>>(listVariant); // Empty

QSequentialIterable iterable = listVariant.value<QSequentialIterable>();
for each (QVariant it in iterable)
    {
        bool convertable = it.canConvert<MyClass>(); // false
        MyClass cl = it.value<MyClass>(); // Empty
        MyClass cl2 = qvariant_cast<MyClass>(it); // Empty

        QObject* object = qvariant_cast<QObject*>(it); // Empty
        MyClass* cl3 = qobject_cast<MyClass*>(object); // Empty

        QVariant var;
        var.setValue(it); 
        MyClass s2 = var.value<MyClass>(); // Empty
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QVariantList`instead of `QList<MyClass>`.

Comment: and how to cast?

Comment: You need `QVariantList listVariant = json_map["ClassList"];` to make possible. Then just `for (const auto& myClassVariant : listVariant) auto myClass = myClassVariant.value<MyClass>();`

Comment: `QVariantList listVariant = json_map["ClassList"]` not possible.
No suitable cast from QVariant to QVariantList

Comment: Have you tried to use [built-in JSON support](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Variable `listVariant` contains `QVariantList` with `QVariantMap` items. To deserealize  `listVariant` into `QList<MyClass>`, you should transform `QVariantMap` to `MyClass` and then `QVariantList` to `QList<MyClass>`. You can tell Qt how to do it by specifying `qvariant_cast` template:

```
template <>
MyClass qvariant_cast<MyClass>(const QVariant& v) {
    MyClass result;
    result.Counter = v.toMap()["Counter"].toInt();
    result.Name = v.toMap()["Name"].toString();
    result.NamesList = v.toMap()["NamesList"].toStringString();
}

template <>
QList<MyClass> qvariant_cast<QList<MyClass>>(const QVariant& v) {
    QList<MyClass> result;
    foreach(const QVariant& item : v.toList()) {
        result.push_back(qvariant_cast<MyClass>(item));
    }
    return result;
}
```